# Can I use Bluemix Cloud Foundry Apps with dotnet core 2?

Tags: .net-core, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, asp.net-core-2.0

File -> New -> Project -> Asp.Net Core 2.0

cf push

```
   /tmp/app/.dotnet/sdk/1.0.4/NuGet.targets(97,5): error : Package Microsoft.AspNetCore 2.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore 2.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0) [/tmp/app/Enerbits.csproj]
       /tmp/app/.dotnet/sdk/1.0.4/NuGet.targets(97,5): error : Package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug 2.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug 2.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0) [/tmp/app/Enerbits.csproj]
       /tmp/app/.dotnet/sdk/1.0.4/NuGet.targets(97,5): error : Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables 2.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables 2.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0) [/tmp/app/Enerbits.csproj]
       /tmp/app/.dotnet/sdk/1.0.4/NuGet.targets(97,5): error : Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine 2.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine 2.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0) [/tmp/app/Enerbits.csproj]
       /tmp/app/.dotnet/sdk/1.0.4/NuGet.targets(97,5): error : Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy 2.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy 2.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0) [/tmp/app/Enerbits.csproj]
       /tmp/app/.dotnet/sdk/1.0.4/NuGet.targets(97,5): error : Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel 2.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel 2.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0) [/tmp/app/Enerbits.csproj]
       /tmp/app/.dotnet/sdk/1.0.4/NuGet.targets(97,5): error : Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets 2.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets 2.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0) [/tmp/app/Enerbits.csproj]
       /tmp/app/.dotnet/sdk/1.0.4/NuGet.targets(97,5): error : Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.CookiePolicy 2.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.CookiePolicy 2.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0) [/tmp/app/Enerbits.csproj]
       /tmp/app/.dotnet/sdk/1.0.4/NuGet.targets(97,5): error : Package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Configuration 2.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Configuration 2.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0) [/tmp/app/Enerbits.csproj]
       /tmp/app/.dotnet/sdk/1.0.4/NuGet.targets(97,5): error : Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions 2.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions 2.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0) [/tmp/app/Enerbits.csproj]
       /tmp/app/.dotnet/sdk/1.0.4/NuGet.targets(97,5): error : Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.KeyDerivation 2.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.KeyDerivation 2.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0) [/tmp/app/Enerbits.csproj]
       /tmp/app/.dotnet/sdk/1.0.4/NuGet.targets(97,5): error : Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration 2.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration 2.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0) [/tmp/app/Enerbits.csproj]
       /tmp/app/.dotnet/sdk/1.0.4/NuGet.targets(97,5): error : Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization 2.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization 2.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0) [/tmp/app/Enerbits.csproj]
       /tmp/app/.dotnet/sdk/1.0.4/NuGet.targets(97,5): error : Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication 2.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication 2.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0) [/tmp/app/Enerbits.csproj]
```

...

And many more errors like this :(

UPDATE:

I got it using the update buildpack from: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/dotnet-core-buildpack.git

I can deploy from my machine if I publish the project first and then call `cf push`, but the Bluemix pipeline deploy task ends with another error:

```
   2017-08-30T23:57:48.25-0300 [STG/0] OUT        Copied 18937 files from /tmp/app/.cloudfoundry/0/nuget to /tmp/cache
   2017-08-30T23:57:48.25-0300 [STG/0] OUT        OK
   2017-08-30T23:57:48.25-0300 [STG/0] OUT -----> Cleaning staging area
   2017-08-30T23:57:48.25-0300 [STG/0] OUT        Removing /tmp/app/.cloudfoundry/0/nuget
   2017-08-30T23:57:48.25-0300 [STG/0] OUT        Removing /tmp/app/.cloudfoundry/0/node
   2017-08-30T23:57:48.25-0300 [STG/0] OUT        OK
   2017-08-30T23:57:48.25-0300 [STG/0] OUT ASP.NET Core buildpack is done creating the droplet
   2017-08-30T23:59:07.01-0300 [STG/0] ERR Failed to compress build artifacts: signal: broken pipe
   2017-08-30T23:59:07.02-0300 [STG/0] OUT Exit status 1
   2017-08-30T23:59:07.16-0300 [STG/0] ERR Staging failed: Exited with status 1
   2017-08-30T23:59:07.19-0300 [STG/0] OUT Destroying container
   2017-08-30T23:59:11.33-0300 [STG/0] OUT Successfully destroyed container
```

Comment: This looks like a `1.0.4` CLI was used to build a 2.0.0 app, for which a `2.0.0` CLI ("SDK") is needed

Comment: Yeap, but how to change that on Bluemix?

Comment: It should be possible as of version 1.0.25 of the .net core build pack.  This release adds support for the 2.0.0 sdk.  Previous build packs support 2.0.0 but only preview releases.  See here for details on what's included with the 1.0.25 build pack -> https://github.com/cloudfoundry/dotnet-core-buildpack/releases/tag/v1.0.25.  You may need to run `cf buildpacks` and see what versions are available on Bluemix.  It might not have the latest as of writing this.

Comment: cf buildpacks only lists old buildpacks, but I'm referring the latest version directly from github. Doing that way works great when I publish to Bluemix from my computer, but not on their pipeline builds :(